# Removing the functions but keeping the shaded region

Tags: manim

I am trying to create a solid shape as a region between two curves revolves around an axis, but I would like to take a more step-by-step approach to what is going on, but to keep it brief:
Because of the way that manim handles parametric surfaces, I need to create two surfaces that revolve around the axis to create the shape that is in between the two functions about the x-axis.
my two functions are x and x^2
when the parametric surfaces are rendered it only creates one parametric surface (the one of x rotated about the x-axis)
below is my code.
How would I adjust surface 2 so that x^2 is rendered properly

Here is my current code. if there is anything else that should be adjusted, please let me know. took out some irrelevant lines of code that did not pertain to the surfaces for ease of readability.

```
class ParaSurf(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
     
        e = ValueTracker(0)
        a = ValueTracker(0)
        
        #Defining Graph1 in 3D Space
        graph2= axes.plot(lambda x: x**2, x_range = [0,1], color = RED)

        #Defining Graph2 in 3D Space
        graph1 = axes.plot( lambda x: x, x_range = [0,1], color = BLUE)

        surface1 = always_redraw(
            lambda: Surface(
                lambda u,v: axes.c2p(v , v*np.cos(u),v*np.sin(u)),
                u_range = [0,e.get_value()],
                v_range = [0,1],
                checkerboard_colors= [BLUE,BLUE]
            )
        )
        
        surface2 = always_redraw(
            lambda: Surface(
                lambda u,v: axes.c2p(v , v*np.cos(u),v*np.sin(u)**2),
                u_range = [0,a.get_value()],
                v_range = [0,1],
                checkerboard_colors= [ORANGE, ORANGE]
            )
        )

        
        self.add(
            surface1, 
            surface2)

        self.play(
            Rotating(graph2 , 
                     axis = RIGHT , 
                     radians = 2*PI,
                     about_point = axes.c2p(0,0,0)),
            
            a.animate.set_value(2*PI),
            
            run_time = 4,
            
            rate_func = rate_functions.linear,
        )
        
        
        
        # self.play(
        #     Rotating(graph1, 
        #              axis = RIGHT , 
        #              radians = 2*PI, 
        #              about_point = axes.c2p(0,0,0)),
            
        #     e.animate.set_value(2*PI),
            
        #     run_time = 4,
            
        #     rate_func = rate_functions.linear
        # )
```

Anything helps, Thank you!